# Struggling using MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to MVC 5 and EF 6, and i'm having lots of trouble of understanding how EF works. I'm using Database first, and used Visual Studio to create the edmx file. Please bear with me if it's long, and i'm really want to learn EF 6 with MVC 5

So in my database i have this

```
Book
-----
Id
Name

AttributeType (ex : Book Size, Book Content, Book Cover)
-------------
Id
Name

Attribute (ex : Pocket, Mature, Young Reader, Hard Cover, Soft Cover) (FK to AttributeType)
--------
Id
AttributeTypeId
Name

BookAttribute (FK to Book and Attribute, PK (AttributeId and BookId)
-------------
AttributeId
BookId
```

So using Database first, VS 2013 creates automatically my entities :

```
public partial class Book {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

and in my DbContext

```
public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
```

and i added some classes

```
  public enum BookAttributeEnum { BookSize = 1, CoverType = 2, BookAudience = 3 }

public partial class Book {
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "BookSize", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public Attribute BookSize
    {
        get { return Attributes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.AttributeTypeId == (int) BookAttributeEnum.BookSize); }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "CoverType", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public Attribute CoverType 
    {
        get { return Attributes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.AttributeTypeId == (int)BookAttributeEnum.CoverType); }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "BookAudience", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public Attribute BookAudience
    {
        get { return Attributes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.AttributeTypeId == (int)AttributeTypeEnum.BookAudience); }
    }
}
```

and in my EditorTemplate for book :

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookSize, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BookSize.Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["BookSizes"], new { @class = "form-control m-bot15" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CoverType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CoverType.Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CoverTypes"], new { @class = "form-control m-bot15" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookAudience, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BookAudience.Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["BookAudiences"], new { @class = "form-control m-bot15" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And my BookContoller

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var Db = new CArtEntities();

        var attributes = Db.Attributes.ToList();


        ViewData["BookSizes"] = attributes.Where(c => c.AttributeTypeId == (int)AttributeTypeEnum.BookSize).ToList()
            .ToListItems(c => c.Id.ToString(), d => d.Name, true);

        ViewData["CoverTypes"] = attributes.Where(c => c.AttributeTypeId == (int)AttributeTypeEnum.CoverType).ToList()
            .ToListItems(c => c.Id.ToString(), d => d.Name, true);

        ViewData["BookAudiences"] = attributes.Where(c => c.AttributeTypeId == (int)AttributeTypeEnum.BookAudience).ToList()
            .ToListItems(c => c.Id.ToString(), d => d.Name, true);

        var art = Db.Books
            .Include("Attributes")
            .Include("ApplicationUser")
            .First(u => u.Id == id);

        return View(art);
    }
```

This is the part where i can't seem find a way to update using Entity Framework

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Book model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var Db = new BookEntities();

            // this is not a good idea, but i don't know how to do it correctly 
            var book = Db.Books
            .Include("Attributes")
            .Include("ApplicationUser")
            .First(u => u.Id == id);

            book.Name = model.Name;
            Db.Entry(book).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;


            List<int> listAttributes = new List<int>();
            listAttributes.Add(Int32.Parse(Request["BookSize.Id"]));
            listAttributes.Add(Int32.Parse(Request["CoverType.Id"]));
            listAttributes.Add(Int32.Parse(Request["BookAudience.Id"]));


            for (int i = book.Attributes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Attribute at = book.Attributes.ToList()[i];

                if (!listAttributes.Contains(at.Id))
                    Db.Entry(at).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }

            foreach (int i in listAttributes)
            {
                if (book.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == i) == null)
                {
                    Attribute at = new Attribute {Id = i};
                    book.Attributes.Add(at);
                }
            }

            await Db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

So my questions :

1. When saving, do i need to re-get the current object that i'm saving
   ? Since i think i need to know which attribute has been removed and
   added.
2. How can i add attribute to the book ? book.Attributes.Add(at); this    line throw an error when i do SaveChangesAsync(), since it seems    want to add a new Attribute
   (which is not correct at all, since it's    already in database, and
   it has an id, and it throw ValidationError    (Name is required)
3. What is the best way to generating dynamically the book Attributes
   in my Editor Template ? Or did i do it correctly by creating
   property for each AttributeType ?

I hope someone can help me out, i've already searching for hours about how to do it, but failed until now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About 1) Yes.

About 2) I answer this together with some other possible improvements of your Edit POST action (from top to bottom):

- Good practice: Instantiate your context in a `using` block to ensure it gets disposed when your processing is finished:

  ```
  using (var Db = new BookEntities())
  {
      //...
  }
  ```
- Prefer the lambda version of `Include` over the string-based version because you will have compile time checks if your navigation properties are correct:

  ```
  .Include(b => b.Attributes)
  .Include(b => b.ApplicationUser)
  ```
- Prefer `Single` (or `SingleOrDefault`) over `First` if you know there can only be one entity with the given `id`.
- Remove the line `Db.Entry(book).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` completely. Your loaded `book` is a tracked entity and EF will recognize that by setting `book.Name = model.Name;` you changed the entity and that it has to be updated when you call `SaveChanges`.
- I believe the `for` loop is wrong because with setting the state of an `Attribute` to `Deleted` EF will try to really delete the attribute from the `Attribute`s table which - I think - is not what you want. You only want to delete the relationship between book and attribute. I would rewrite the `for` loop like so:

  ```
  foreach (var at in book.Attributes.ToList())
  {
      if (!listAttributes.Contains(at.Id))
          book.Attributes.Remove(at);
  }
  ```

  Change tracking will detect that you removed the attribute from the book and translate that to a DELETE statement in the link table `BookAttributes` (and not in the `Attributes` table!).
- I would prefer `if (!book.Attributes.Any(c => c.Id == i))` over `if (book.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == i) == null)`. It expresses the intent of the code better.
- To avoid adding a new attribute to the `Attribute` table (your real question 2) attach it to the context:

  ```
  Attribute at = new Attribute {Id = i};
  Db.Attributes.Attach(at);
  book.Attributes.Add(at);
  ```

About 3) Seems OK to me. Some people (including myself) don't like the `ViewData` dictionary and prefer to put every data the view needs into a single ViewModel class and pass that as the model to the view. But it's perhaps a matter of taste and discussing that in detail would let your question explode a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but Db.Attributes.Attach(at) throw me an error `An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.`

Comment: @puntapret: Can you try to replace `Attribute at = new Attribute {Id = i}; Db.Attributes.Attach(at);` by `Attribute at = Db.Attributes.Find(i);`? I'm not sure how this exception could occur with your code though.

Comment: I changed that,now it throws me an error : `Unable to update the EntitySet 'BookAttribute' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <DeleteFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.`. Which is weird, because the BookAttribute table has primary key.

Comment: @puntapret: The `BookAttribute` table is just a many-to-many link table, right? Do you have a separate entity for this in your model? You should not have one. Is your edmx file up-to-date with the database schema?

Comment: You are correct @slauma, my edmx file is not up to date. Thanks so much for your help